# I can't start my ubuntu. Grub screen invisible. Windows automatic

Tags: grub2, 16.04, 16.10

I had windows10 on my computer. Yesterday i installed ubuntu 16 alongside with windows. Now i can't open my ubuntu.

I installed ubuntu using usb.

How can i start my ubuntu?

There is no grub screen in the beginning.

Comment: Was Ubuntu installed in the same mode (UEFI/legacy) as Windows 10?

Comment: it was installed in uefi mode . yes.

Comment: A boot-repair report would provide much useful information so suggestions may be made.  If you run the EFI menu (some function key at power-up to give boot choices for devices/oses) do you see ubuntu (or maybe select hdd, then get the Windows/ubuntu choice)?  Do you see the Ubuntu partitions from the live-media?  What model is your machine (some have quirks to work around)?

Comment: When i start computer with usb, a screen with choices of 'install ubuntu', 'try ubuntu' ... comes up. But i am sure that i installed ubuntu. If i open without usb. It directly starts windows.